# Document fragment appearing in request URLs in PHP script

Tags: php, apache, header, request

While logging HTTP requests to a file I have found something I would not expect.

I just put in the log the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Guess what I have found, an url with #fragment attached:

```
18/05: requested cat/page.html#fragment
```

Note out of 2477 line of logs I found only one line with fragment attached

Everyone know (should) that fragment is never known server-side but only javascript code can get it. So what is happening here?

I am running PHP 5.3 on Apache 2.X (Debian).

Comment: Log the user agent too. Could be a malfunctioning spider. Could be someone playing around with Fiddler, could be some poor javascript that sends you that url etc.

Comment: I can start loggin the ua too but it can take days for that log to reapper

Comment: Could have been a request for cat/page.html%23fragment

Comment: @FrankFarmer: Which is the same thing.

Comment: who edited my title it was so nice before xx

Comment: I've also edited the question to remove the emoticon, improve some formating/grammar, and given you a +1 since in reality it isn't a bad question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assertion that "fragment is never known server-side but only javascript code can get it" is a little short-sighted.

Whilst it's true that, in general operation with a conventional browser, a fragment is not included in the request-to-server, there is nothing stopping me from writing whatever I want in an HTTP request.

```
echo "GET /lol/werent/expecting/this#were_you HTTP/1.1" > /dev/tcp/yourwebsite.com/80
```

Someone's testing, someone's playing, someone's playing a bizarre hack attempt, or someone's using a buggy browser.

I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Never mind, the part is not sent in request. I should read slower.

Comment: I would suggest turning request URI's into a more canonical form before passing them to your caching system. This would be where you expand aliases, etc (and remove sections you don't want, i.e. fragments).